# Annotating heatmap in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have to do three plots (contour, 3d surface, and heatmap) in matplotlib. The corresponding grid dimension for the three plots are ([0, 0], [0, 1], and [1, 0:1])

I have a few problems

1. The text annotation for heatmap (ax3), seem to fly out of ax3, into
   ax1 and ax2. How can I constrain them to be within the ax3 only ?
2. Is this the fastest way to annotate text assuming that I do not want
   to use seaborn ?

Can I get some tips on how to resolve my problems ?

Below is the code snippet to perform the plot operation

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gspec
from scipy.interpolate import griddata
import pyautogui
from scipy import stats

x = pyautogui.size()
width = x.width
height = x.height

x = np.arange(0, 10, 0.5)
y = np.arange(0, 10, 0.5)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
data = 2 * (np.sin(X) + np.sin(3 * Y))

fig = plt.figure()
fig.set_figheight(height / 100)
fig.set_figwidth(width / 100)
fig.set_dpi(100)
gs = gspec.GridSpec(nrows=2, ncols=2)
ax1 = plt.subplot(gs[0, 0])
ax2 = plt.subplot(gs[0, 1], projection='3d')
ax3 = plt.subplot(gs[1, 0:1])
ctr = ax1.contourf(X, Y, data, 10, cmap='viridis')
ax1.clabel(ctr, inline=True, fontsize=8)
cbar = plt.colorbar(ctr, ax=ax1)
cbar.set_label('ColorbarLabel', size=15)
surf = ax2.plot_surface(X, Y, data, cmap='jet')
cbar1 = plt.colorbar(surf, ax=ax2)
cbar1.set_label('Colorbar2', size=15)
hmap = ax3.pcolormesh(X, Y, data, cmap='viridis')
cbar2 = plt.colorbar(hmap, ax=ax3)
for y in range(data.shape[0]):
    for x in range(data.shape[1]):
        ax3.text(x, y, '%.1f' % data[y, x], size=3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want your heatmap to cover both columns. To achieve that you have to use `ax3 = plt.subplot(gs[1, 0:2])`: this tells matplotlib to use columns 0 and 1 (2 is excluded).

> The text annotation for heatmap (ax3), seem to fly out of ax3, into ax1 and ax2. How can I constrain them to be within the ax3 only ?

That's because you are using the wrong coordinates in `ax3.text`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gspec
from scipy.interpolate import griddata
import pyautogui
from scipy import stats

x = pyautogui.size()
width = x.width
height = x.height

x = np.arange(0, 10, 0.5)
y = np.arange(0, 10, 0.5)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
data = 2 * (np.sin(X) + np.sin(3 * Y))

fig = plt.figure()
fig.set_figheight(height / 100)
fig.set_figwidth(width / 100)
fig.set_dpi(100)
gs = gspec.GridSpec(nrows=2, ncols=2)
ax1 = plt.subplot(gs[0, 0])
ax2 = plt.subplot(gs[0, 1], projection='3d')
ax3 = plt.subplot(gs[1, 0:2])
ctr = ax1.contourf(X, Y, data, 10, cmap='viridis')
ax1.clabel(ctr, inline=True, fontsize=8)
cbar = plt.colorbar(ctr, ax=ax1)
cbar.set_label('ColorbarLabel', size=15)
surf = ax2.plot_surface(X, Y, data, cmap='jet')
cbar1 = plt.colorbar(surf, ax=ax2)
cbar1.set_label('Colorbar2', size=15)
hmap = ax3.pcolormesh(X, Y, data, cmap='viridis')
cbar2 = plt.colorbar(hmap, ax=ax3)
for i in range(data.shape[0]):
    for j in range(data.shape[1]):
        ax3.text(x[j], y[i], '%.1f' % data[i, j], size=5)
```